# Finding the percentage of a specific value in the column of a data set

Tags: r, percentage

I have a dataset called college, and one of the columns is 'accepted'. There are two values for this column - 1 (which means student was accepted) and 0 (which means student was not accepted). I was to find the accepted student percentage.

I did this...

```
table(college$accepted)
```

which gave me the frequency of 1 and 0. (1 = 44,224 and 0 = 75,166). I then manually added those two values together (119,390) and divided the 44,224/119,390. This is fine and gets me the value I was looking for. But I would really like to know how I could do this with R code, since I'm sure there is a way to do it that I just haven't thought of.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can use `prop.table` like below

```
prop.table(table(college$accepted))["1"]
```

Comment: Thank you! Just a question - would this work with a non-numerical column? Say I had yes and no values, could I just use this function and replace "1" with "Yes"? Or what if there were more than two values - would it work all the same?

Comment: @zinger001 It works with non-numerical column and more than two values. You just need to type the name of interested value, e.g., "Yes", to see its proportion.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a simple 0/1 column then you only need take the column mean.

```
mean_accepted <- mean(df$accepted)
```

Answer (score 0):

you could first sum the column, and the count the total number in the column

```
sum(college$accepted)/length(college$accepted)
```

Answer (score 0):

To make the code more explicit and describe your intent better, I suggest using a condition to identify the cases that meet your criteria for inclusion. For example:

```
college$accepted == 1
```

Then take the average of the logical vector to compute the proportion (between 0  and 1), multiply by 100 to make it a percentage.

```
100 * mean(college$accepted == 1, na.rm = TRUE)
```